# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, ajax-upload

I am using `ajaxupload.js` from [here](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) and I see the file doing the upload work alright. But I am getting `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"id":"006","path":"006.png"}</pre>` in the response.

I think the response should be just `{"id":"006","path":"006.png"}` but for some reasons it got wrapped around `<pre>` and hence the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

I am using spring mvc 3, tomcat. I am using `java.io.Writer` to write the response as `writer.write(json.toString());`

Could someone help me understand this error and how to resolve it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

**CODE**:

```
<form id="app-form" class="cols" action="#" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="w50">                              
        <!--  set of form fields -->
    </fieldset>   
    <fieldset class="w50">                              
        <button id="uploadButton" class="csbutton-grey" >Upload</button>
        <ul id="locationImages"></ul>
    </fieldset>
<div style="float: left;">
    <button type="submit" class="cool-button">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){
    var button = $('#uploadButton'), interval;

    new AjaxUpload(button, {
        action: 'uploadImage', 
        name: 'qqfile',
        responseType: "json",
        onSubmit : function(file, ext){
            this.disable();
            console.log("file - " + file);
            console.log("ext - " + ext);
            if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
                alert('Error: invalid file extension');
                return false; 
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"file",
                    data:'file='+file,
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        console.log(jqXHR.status);
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR.status);
                    },
                });                 
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            this.enable();
            console.log("file - " + file);
            console.log("response.id - " + response.id + ", response.path - " + response.path);
            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#locationImages').text(file);                      
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `responseType` property as `json` in AjaxUpload?

Comment: I totally missed to set that. Now that have done it that error was gone but I am getting `[object Object]` for response and a new error came for which I had to replace `<!DOCTYPE html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` to work around it, otherwise IE 8 was not happy and the styling of the page went awry with it. And `https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload` is not working with IE 8 or Mozilla 9 :(.

Comment: But working with Safari 5.1.4  and Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m. I am getting `[object Object]` for response and It is notworking with IE 8 or Mozilla 9. What do I do? I am using https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload.

Comment: If you alert a json object, you will get [object Object]. This means you have got the proper object back. You can try alerting obj.id, obj.path to see if you are getting the proper values.

Comment: Oh damn. Yep, I just got the value extracted from the response. What do I do with Mozilla and IE? They both give me `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`. Sometimes even Chrome 19 does that too. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have added the code in the post as an update. I get http://wikedlynotsmat.com/current-form-page.html# for the url and get HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported for the error when I click on Upload button.

Comment: The url I get directed to is the the url of the current page with `#` appended to it. So if the form page where I have the upload option as well is on `wikedlynotsmat.com/current-form-page.html` then when I click on the `Upload` button I get redirected to `wikedlynotsmat.com/current-form-page.html#` with `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported` meesage. Sorry for the url confusion earlier in case you noticed them during comment updates. Thanks again.

Comment: If I change the upload element in html file to                        `<div id="uploadButton" >Upload</div>                   <ul id="locationImages"></ul>` then I see that it is no more clickable in firefox 9 and IE 8 but works with both chrome 19 and safari 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send JSON to the client, use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). Spring MVC had native support for it. Create a bean class like this:

```
public class Result{
private String id;
private String path;
public Result(String id, String path){
this.id=id;this.path=path;}
public Result(){}
// add getters and setters
}
```

Now create your controller method like this

```
@ResponseBody // this is important
@RequestMapping("/path/to/mapping")
public Result someMethodName(SomeParameter param1, SomeParameter param2){
    // do something here
    return new Result(id, path);
}
```

As long as you have Jackson on your classpath and have configured your Spring app through `<mvc:annotation-config />`, this will automatically serialize your response Object to correct JSON (including correct mime type)

Comment: Yep. That is what I always use for returning json data, but with https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:580)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:183)
 at org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpResponse.getBody(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:71) ...` :(